# Can I have Google search results always filtered?

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to have Google search results always filtered? I am constantly clicking on "only show results from the past year" and I would like to make this default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following your Google bookmark and/or homepage:

`https://www.google.com/webhp?tbs=qdr:y`

The reason for the link is that there's no way to default the search parameters for "Since"